# Convert if/else to ternary operator Java

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-operator

My function setA() looks like this:

```
public double setA(){
    double a;
    
    aField.getText() == null || aField.getText().trim().isEmpty() ? a = 1 : a = Double.parseDouble(aField.getText());

    //a = aField.getText() == null || aField.getText().trim().isEmpty() ? a = 1 : a = Double.parseDouble(aField.getText());

    //return aField.getText() == null || aField.getText().trim().isEmpty() ? a = 1 : a = Double.parseDouble(aField.getText());

    /*if(aField.getText() == null || aField.getText().trim().isEmpty())
        a = 1;
    else
       a = Double.parseDouble(aField.getText());*/
   
    return a;
}
```

I want to get rid of if/else and rewrite it with the ternary operator.
None of these 3 ternary options work and, on a build, they show the same mistake:

> java: unexpected type
> required: variable
> found:    value

Meanwhile the commented if/else block works just fine.
Passing TextField aField into the function and working through this. doesn't help + before building I see

> Variable 'a' might not have been initialized

What's the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your ternary attempts is that they are not corrected in terms of syntax:

```
//a = aField.getText() == null || aField.getText().trim().isEmpty() ? a = 1 : a = Double.parseDouble(aField.getText());
```

For the Java language specification ([§15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)):

15.25. Conditional Operator ? :

> The conditional operator ? : uses the boolean value of one expression
> to decide which of two other expressions should be evaluated.
>
> ConditionalExpression:
> ConditionalOrExpression
> ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : ConditionalExpression

So in your case is a = (conditional expression) **?** value of 'a' if `conditional expression` is true **:** value of 'a' if the  `conditional expression` is false ;

```
a = aField.getText() == null || aField.getText().trim().isEmpty() 
  ? 1 
  : Double.parseDouble(aField.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = (aField.getText() == null || aField.getText().trim().isEmpty())
 ? 1.0 : Double.parseDouble(aField.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty fine, except one thing the way how you set `a`variable.

```
double a = <condition> ? <true> : <false>:
```

You can additionally use `Apache` utils to simplify a bit the code.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public double setA() {
    return StringUtils.isBlank(aField.getText()) ? 1 : Double.parseDouble(aField.getText());
}

public double setA() {
    String str = aField.getText();
    return str == null || str.trim().isEmpty() ? 1 : Double.parseDouble(str.trim());
}
```